# Expose mongodb database connection to pages in Next.js 6 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, next.js

I am building an app with [Next.js v6](https://nextjs.org/), and I would like to fill pages with results from a local mongodb database.

Ideally, I would like to do something as simple as [this example from the tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows), but **instead of using an api fetch, just send a query to my mongodb on localhost.**

*Example from Next.js tutorial*

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Batman TV Shows</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.shows.map(({show}) => (
        <li key={show.id}>
          <Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?id=${show.id}`}>
            <a>{show.name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman')
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`)

  return {
    shows: data
  }
}

export default Index
```

My problem is in trying to get my database connected and exposed to the app so that I can do something like this on a page names resources.js:

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Resources = (props) => {
    <Layout>
        <h3>Resources</h3>
        <ul style={listStyle}>
            {props.resources.map(({resource}) => (
                <li key={resource._id}>
                    <Link href={resource.link}>
                        <a>{resource.title}</a>
                    </Link>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </Layout>
};

Resources.getInitialProps = async function() {  

    // get query from mongo DB
    // req is 'undefined' -- I want to see the db here
    const list = await req.db.get('resources').find();
    return list;

}

export default Resources;
```

But I don't know how I can expose the database in a function that could be accessed from pages anywhere in the app. It seems that older tutorials of examples used something like `server.use((req, res, next) => { req.db = dbToExpose });` in the main `index.js` file, but this doesn't seem to be working with Next.js v. 6??

*For example, [this sample repo](https://github.com/vkarpov15/reading-list) from [this tutorial](http://thecodebarbarian.com/building-a-nextjs-app-with-mongodb.html) doesn't seem to work for me with the latest version of Next.js. The db exposed trough `req.db` comes up as 'undefined' when you try to access it from a a page. But perhaps I am missing some other problem.*

Here's my attempt in my base server file at exposing the db so I can access it from files in `pages/`:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const monk = require('monk')('localhost/myDatabase')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

  // This is not working to expose the db!
  server.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.db = monk
    next()
  });

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not expose any secure data or do database connecting in Nextjs pages. This post show the way for [connect to database with NextJs](https://cloudreports.net/create-custom-self-api-next-js-api-server/) without api

Comment: I ended up creating an API interface (in the same app as a NextJS [custom express server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express)), but this is also a really interesting way of handling the problem. Thank you. When I first asked the question I was just learning and didn't understand about APIs and connecting to databases.

Comment: API is a must-have thing when working with NextJs. But on server side, i think it's better if we can do direct-call to the service without calling internal api. By that way, we can reduce the time on server side rendering

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if something like this would be possible earlier, for exactly this reason (reducing SSR times). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to wrap your Mongo DB in an API, which you could serve with the next server to avoid CORS issues. Next does not expose the Express request to the pages since this is not available on client rendering.

Comment: I think this is basically what I ended up doing. But I created a separate express API server that connects to Mongo DB with Mongoose, and then I just make all the db calls to the API through http requests.  On my API server I added `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` etc... to mitigate CORS issues. But you're saying it might be better just to put that whole API on the same express server as next is running on?

Comment: Hi @BillD, I was just suggesting that it might be easier. I usually keep them separate as well, serving the API from cloud functions, but its often easier to keep the source code together and not have to worry about multiple hosting accounts, etc. Glad that worked out for you!